# C++ floating point number is way off

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I just recently encountered this problem in c++

```
std::cout << -5.0000004768371582 + 5 << "\n";
```

This will print -4.76837e-007 even though you would think it would print something like 0.000000476...
I know floating points aren't always correct, but I've never seen this before.
I've also seen this happen with other numbers.

Why is this. And how could I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number is correct, floating point does have some accuracy issues, but in this case it is not the case.

In this case it is just a matter of notation.

-4.76837e-007 means  [image]

so it is correct

Answer (score 5):

The output you're encountering is known as [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). If you want it to be displayed in *fixed point notation*, used `std::fixed`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << -5.0000004768371582 + 5 << "\n";
}
```